# Trying to get the shortest path (bfs) in directed graph in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am looking for a code to find the shortest path a in directed graph.

Is there somewhere I can find one?

(can be based of BFS)

Comment: why erlang tag? Do you want code in erlang?

Comment: @ravi that's what it says in the title of the question, but the OP should have made it clearer, true enough.

Comment: ok...OP also didn't mention if he wants it for single source shortest path or all pair shortest paths.

Comment: @OP: Do you have negative weights on edges?

Comment: I think you have the answer in your question: Do a breadth first search on your graph. It will give you the shortest path. All you need to do is code it in Erlang. That will depend on how your data is organised.

Comment: sorry , i didnt described it well.
i have a master procsses , that created a graph.
the master know all the connectivity of the nodes .

i need to calc for each node the shortedt path to all the other nodes.

(the graph is a meshgrid.

i know that i have to use BFS , but im looking for code if there are that all ready made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Erlang Digraph Library](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html) and function get_short_path/3, which takes a directed graph and the start/end vertices couple.